# how to use @> operator with psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, psql

Psycopg2 keeps giving me the following error:

```
    psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: numrange @> integer

    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts
```

I'd like to get the range in which a value(such as 1) falls from a table in my postgres db that has a column with int4range type.

```
    select price,weight_kgs @>1 from weight_categories;
```

NB: The code runs when i use it in terminal

This is the structure of my table:

```
      Column   |   Type   | Collation | Nullable |                       
    Default                        
    ------------+----------+-----------+----------+------------------- 
    -----------------------------------
     weight_id  | integer  |           | not null | 
    nextval('weight_categories_weight_id_seq'::regclass)
     weight_kgs | numrange |           | not null | 
     price      | integer  |           | not null |
```

Answer (score 0):

numrange type  requires that a value being checked have at least one decimal point. This

```
     select price,weight_kgs @>1.0 from weight_categories;
```

will work.
If you are getting the value from a user in your python program.
You can add the decimal points using,

```
       num = float(value)
```

Where value can be 1 or any other integer.